.NET HTML grid using a model is lost when navigating to the second page in the paging structure."
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function SeAction () {
    var ekbilgidetay = document.getElementById("#EkbilgiDetayListesi").value;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '@Url.Action("SinifEslestirme", "Home")',
      data: '{ tempDataValue:"' + ekbilgidetay + '"}',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "text",
    });
  }
</script>


[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult SinifEslestirme(string DetayNo) {
  var liste = Classes.SinifEslestirme.SinifEkBilgiDetayGetirmeListesi(DetayNo, HttpContext.Session["YETKI"].ToString());
  if (liste != null && liste.Count > 0) {  
    return View("SinifEslestirme", liste);
  }
}


<h3>Sınıf Eşleştirme</h3>
@if (Model != null) {
  <h3>@TempData["MalEkbilgiNo"].ToString() - 
      @TempData["MalEkbilgiAdi"].ToString()   |   
      @TempData["MalEkbilgiDetayNo"].ToString() - 
      @TempData["MalEkbilgiDetayAdi"].ToString()</h3>
  @ViewBag.mesaj
  @Html.ActionLink("<<Önceki Sayfa", "EkBilgi", "Home", new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
  <br />
  <br />
  @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns => {
    columns.Add(c => c.Mal_grup_no).Titled("Grup");
    columns.Add(c => c.Mal_grup_adi).Titled("Grup Adı").Filterable(true);
    columns.Add(c => c.Mal_altgrup_no).Titled("Alt Grup");
    columns.Add(c => c.Mal_altgrup_adi).Titled("Alt Grup Adı").Filterable(true);
    columns.Add(c => c.Mal_sinif_no).Titled("Sınıf");
    columns.Add(c => c.Mal_sinif_adi).Titled("Sınıf Adı").Filterable(true);
    columns.Add().Titled("Çalışır").Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).SetWidth(20).RenderValueAs(c => {
    var isChecked = c.Calisir == 1 ? "checked" : "";
    var checkboxHtml = $@"
    <input type='checkbox' onclick=""updateSelectedValues(this, '{c.Mal_grup_no}{c.Mal_altgrup_no}{c.Mal_sinif_no}{c.Mal_ekbilgi_detay_no}')""
            {isChecked}>";
      return Html.Raw(checkboxHtml);
    });
  }).WithPaging(20).Sortable(true)
}

I am sending ekbilgidetay number to the SinifEslestirme ActionResult.
I am receiving a list and displaying it as a grid on the SinifEslestirme page
but grid using a model is lost when navigating to the second page in the paging structure.
How can I load the data into the grid once and enable pagination for navigating through it?

Your ID cannot start with # so your getElementById is wrong. But why use DOM access when you have jQuery where the # IS used for ID
var ekbilgidetay = $("#EkbilgiDetayListesi").val(), data = JSON.stringify({ tempDataValue: ekbilgidetay }); $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: '@Url.Action("SinifEslestirme", "Home")',  data: data, .....
